# How can I lock the viewpager while im zooming one of the viewpager picture

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have a viewPage with an array have 3 picture and i want to lock the viewPager when zoom one of them cause when i scroll on the right side the next photo appear ! 
here is my code

```
enter code here
 public class ExploreImageAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
boolean touchEvent;
private int[] exploreImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.carfourele,
    R.drawable.carfourele2,
    R.drawable.carfourele3,
    R.drawable.carfourele4
};

private LayoutInflater inflater;
ExploreImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i=1 ; i<=exploreImages.length ; i++){
```

}
    }

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
  return exploreImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
               View topImageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_images, container, false);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        TouchImageView  imageView= (TouchImageView)topImageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setFocusable(true);
                imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setImageResource(exploreImages[position]);
          imageView.setMaxZoom(4f);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(topImageLayout, 0);
              return topImageLayout;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to create a custom ViewPager and override the `onTouchEvent()` and `onTouchInterceptEvent()` methods. For example,

```
public class LockedViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean pagingEnabled;

    public LockedViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        pagingEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (pagingEnabled) {
           return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (pagingEnabled) {
           return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param pagingEnabled
     *      if true, ViewPager acts as normal
     *      if false, ViewPager cannot be scrolled by a user's touch
     */
    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean pagingEnabled) {
        this.pagingEnabled = pagingEnabled;
    }
}
```

Whenever you'd like to prevent the user from being able to scroll, simply call `lockedViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);`
And then when you'd like to turn it back on, `lockedViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);`

Just to give a brief explanation, the onTouchEvent methods are normally the entry point for handling paging behavior, so we're simply stopping it right at the beginning whenever paging is not enabled. Also, the methods normally return true if they have handled the event, so we must return false to indicate that we have ignored it.

In order to incorporate this into your app, first add the LockedViewPager to your activity's XML, but don't forget to the name of `your_app` and `your_package` to create the path to your LockedViewPager class (if you're using Android Studio, beginning to type LockedViewPager should automatically recognize and suggest the path for you):

```
<com.your_app.your_package.LockedViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lockedViewPager"/>
```

Then, you would use this in your activity like so:

```
public class MyActivity {

    private LockedViewPager lockedViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // other activity setup, etc.

        lockedViewPager = (LockedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.lockedViewPager);

        // set up pager, set its adapter and any listeners, etc.

    }

    /*
     * Call this method once you've zoomed, for example
     */
    public void onZoom() {
        lockedViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
    }

    /*
     * Don't forget to call this method at some time later to re-enable the paging
     */
    public void resumePaging() {
        lockedViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I created new class as yours (LockedViewPager) but what should i pass from the first class which written above! to the constructor LockedViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)??

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example of how you could include it in your XML and Activity, please check that out, and consider marking my answer correct if it works for you

Comment: @FrankCangialosi can u please help me when will i call these functions i also have the same problem please guide me   ....onZoom() and resumePaging()

Comment: Well if you have the exact same problem as the OP, then you would call onZoom() whenever the user zooms in, which will prevent them from being able to scroll while zoomed in. Then, when they zoom back out, or whenever you want to allow them to page again, you call resumePaging()

However, you don't need to use those two methods specifically, I just named them that way based on the problem in question. You can call setPagingEnabled() whenever you want, the point is that if you call setPagingEnabled(true), the user will be able to scroll, and if you call setPagingEnabled(false), they will not.

Comment: Does that answer your question?